# Rearranging the output of mysql query

Tags: mysql

When I run the following Query:

```
SELECT ticket.id, th.ticket_id , th.id, th.name, th.create_time 
  FROM ticket_history th
  JOIN ticket ON  th.ticket_id =  ticket.id 
 WHERE (
        th.name LIKE  '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th1 
         WHERE th1.ticket_id = ticket.id AND th1.name LIKE '%\%Close')
       )
    OR (
        th.name LIKE  '%\%Close'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket_history th2 
         WHERE th2.ticket_id = ticket.id AND th2.name LIKE '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%')
       )
 ORDER BY th.ticket_id , th.id ASC;
```

I get the following output:

```
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | ticket_id | id  |                   name                    |     create_time     |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  3 |         3 |   5 | %%2013060810000021%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%3 | 2013-06-08 21:59:03 |
|  3 |         3 |  82 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:50:49 |
|  5 |         5 |  64 | %%2013060910000019%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%5 | 2013-06-09 17:12:09 |
|  5 |         5 |  85 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-10 11:51:10 |
|  8 |         8 |  98 | %%2013061110000014%%Raw%%3 normal%%new%%8 | 2013-06-11 19:05:06 |
|  8 |         8 | 109 | %%Close                                   | 2013-06-17 23:57:35 |
+----+-----------+-----+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

In the above output the entry which contains "Raw" and "new" keyword show me when that particular ticket was open and the entry which contains "Close" keyword shows me when that particular ticket was closed.

What changes do I need to make in order to get the output as below:

```
+----+-----------+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | ticket_id | id |      Open time       |     Close_time      |
+----+-----------+----+----------------------+---------------------+
|  3 |         3 |  5 | 2013-06-08 21:59:03  | 2013-06-10 11:50:49 |
|  5 |         5 | 64 | 2013-06-09 17:12:09  | 2013-06-10 11:51:10 |
|  8 |         8 | 98 | 2013-06-11 19:05:06  | 2013-06-17 23:57:35 |
+----+-----------+----+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to need the `ticket` table. The output does contain the `ticket.id` column, but it is always same as `ticket_history.ticket_id`, which is also included in the output.

In view of the above, the following query reads only `ticket_history`. It uses conditional aggregation to build the output you are after:

```
SELECT
  ticket_id,
  MIN(id) AS id,
  MAX(CASE name WHEN '%%Close' THEN NULL ELSE create_time END) AS open_time,
  MAX(CASE name WHEN '%%Close' THEN create_time ELSE NULL END) AS close_time
FROM ticket_history
GROUP BY
  ticket_id
HAVING COUNT(name LIKE '%\%Close'            OR NULL) = 1
   AND COUNT(name LIKE '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%' OR NULL) = 1
;
```

The `HAVING` clause makes sure a ticket has both open and close rows. The `OR NULL` trick is explained in this Stack Overflow answer:

- [Why do I need “OR NULL” in MySQL when counting rows with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011239/why-do-i-need-or-null-in-mysql-when-counting-rows-with-a-condition/5011311#5011311)

The `id` column is derived as `MIN(id)` on the assumption that a Close row will always appear *after* the corresponding Open one, and therefore the latter's `id` will always be lower than the former's.

The `open_time` and `close_time` values are obtained using conditional aggregation. Depending on whether the `name` column matches the `'%\%Close'` pattern or not, the `create_time` column is aggregated as either `close_time` or `open_time`.

You can use this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45213/1) to try the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `ticket_history` table twice:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       th1.id AS open_id,   th1.name AS open_name,   th1.create_time AS open_time,
       th2.id AS close_id,  th2.name AS close_name,  th2.create_time AS close_time
  FROM ticket AS t
    JOIN ticket_history AS th1 
      ON  th1.ticket_id = t.id 
      AND th1.name LIKE '%\%Raw\%% %\%new\%%'                   
    LEFT JOIN ticket_history AS th2 
      ON  th2.ticket_id = t.id
      AND th2.name LIKE '%\%Close'  
 ORDER BY t.id , th1.id ;
```

The above will also show the opened but not closed yet tickets. If you want only the closed ones, change the `LEFT` join to `INNER` join.